# How to handle error responses in a chain of CompletableFutures?

Tags: java, asynchronous, exception, completable-future

I have a long chain of completable futures in my project, with each step calling a backend API, which can give multiple error responses and one success response. Now, after parsing the response, I need to judge if it's an error, then I need to show to the user. I also need to know which stage in my chain, produced this error.

My approach right now (shown below) is to throw a Runtime Exception whenever I encounter an error response, and then append exceptionally block to my chain. I feel that this is not the best way to do it, since a runtime exception doesn't fit in this scenario. It also makes my code ugly, since I have to do it whenever I process a response, leading to an extra exception check. Is there a better way to do it?

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    //some api call
    Response response = request.send();

    if(response.hasError()){ //this is what I am doing right now
        logger.error("this is error response");
        throw new ResponseErrorException("Error response received for request");
    }
})
```

This is basically repeated for every step in the chain.

Summary: If I get a failure response in any of the steps in a CompletableFuture chain, what's a good way to propagate it to the user?

Edit: If there's no better approach, please feel free to share your views on my approach.

Comment: "I have to do it whenever I process a response, leading to an extra exception check". I thought you only do it once, at the end of the chain?

Comment: No i do it at every step, since each step has an API response which might be an error

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is using [Decorator](https://www.baeldung.com/java-decorator-pattern) pattern for the responses. Suggest you have something like this

```
CompletableFuture
.supplyAsync(() -> {
    //some api call
    Response response = request.send();

    if(response.hasError()){ //this is what I am doing right now
        throw new ResponseErrorException("Error response received for request");
    }
})
.thenApply(() -> {
    //some api call
    Response response = request.send();

    if(response.hasError()){ //this is what I am doing right now
        throw new ResponseErrorException("Another Error response received for request");
    }
})
.exceptionally(ex -> "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
```

and if you would like to avoid duplication in throwing exceptions you could use following approach

```
CompletableFuture
.supplyAsync(() -> {
    //some api call
    Response response = ThrowExceptionOnErrorResponse(request.send());
})
.thenApply(() -> {
    //some api call
    Response response = ThrowExceptionOnErrorResponse(request.send());
    }
})
.exceptionally(ex -> "Error: " + ex.getMessage());

class ThrowExceptionOnError implements Response {

    Response originalResponse;

    ThrowExceptionOnError(Response originalResp) {
        if(response.hasError()) {
           throw new ResponseErrorException("Another Error response received for request");
        }
        this.originalResponse = originalResponse;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Extracting out to a separate method definitely makes it clean, however we're still throwing exceptions at every step. I also need to track the step which threw the exception as well, that will also need to be passed in the common method.
I think you're also implying that throwing exception at every step is the only way of achieving what I want.